# Reset to the first view ios application

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, reset, superview

I have an app such that it has a authentication screen as its first view. if authentication is successful, a tabbarcontroller is loaded. All views in the tab bar require the user to enter a pin code. What I need to do is that when the user enters incorrect password 5 times, an alert view pops up, and the application goes back to the authentication screen. I am able to remove the tabbarcontroller.view from superview. But after that the screen is blank. The authentication screen does not show. What can I do to achieve my task?

EDIT:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (actionSheet == alertDeActivate) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Alert Deactivated");
            UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
            if (!window) {
                window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            [self.tabBarController.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
            [self.dataLayer notifySplashRemoved];
        }
    }
}

-(void)notifySplashRemoved
{    
    bool userAuthenticated = [self checkForUserAuthentication];
    bool appAcivated = [self checkForAppActivation];
    if (userAuthenticated)
    {
        if(appAcivated == false){
            self.activationScreen = [[ActivationScreen alloc] init];
            [self.activationScreen setdataLayer:self];
            [self.window addSubview:self.activationScreen.view];
        }
        else
        {

            _tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
            manageVRNs = [[ManageVehiclesView alloc] init];
            aboutUsView = [[AboutUsView alloc] init];
            helpView = [[HelpView alloc] init];
            optionsView = [[OptionsView alloc] init];

            _manage = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:manageVRNs];
            [_manage.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
            _about = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUsView];
            [_about setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
            _help = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:helpView];
            [_help.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


            self.navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:optionsView];
            [self setnavigationCon:self.navCon];
            [optionsView setdataLayer:self];
            if ([navCon.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_bar.png"];
                [self.navCon.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
                [optionsView addSelfView:window];
            }

            _tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navCon, _manage, _about, _help, nil];
            [_tbc.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_bg.png"]];
            [_tbc.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_selected.png"]];
            [window addSubview:_tbc.view];

        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.authenticationScreen = [[AuthenticationScreen alloc] init];
        [self.authenticationScreen setdataLayer:self];
        [self.window addSubview:self.authenticationScreen.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code on how you're removing the `tabbarcontroller` and adding the autnentication screen back.

Comment: see edit. dataLayer is a class of NSObject

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine.
The screen is most probably blank because there's no view added to it. This can happen if either your `window` variable is nil, or you're passing `nil` on `addSubView:`.

My suggestion is that you place a breakpoint in `notifySplashRemoved` and check that both `window` (or `self.window`) and view you're passing to `addSubView:` are valid (not `nil`).